# When two threads run a specific process separately, will the program end when one thread returns the value?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, ocaml, threadpool

Here's the scenario:

You have two threads (which represent different machines) who take the same input from a singular data source, run through the same processes (which do not depend on any shared resources) and return the same value.

If one thread (read:machine) is faster than the other and finishes first, will the program accept that value and end, or will it wait for the other thread to finish? If the answer is the latter, is there anyway to force the program to take the first answer?

The practical reason for this would be to handle unbearably slow machines.

Comment: Which programming language? When you say different machines do you refer to distributed computing or is this the same process with two threads spawned?

Comment: I'm using ocaml.
I just said machine as a metaphor, its just threading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely you to decide. If you spawn two threads, you can control them from the parent process and decide the behavior you want. You may `wait` on both threads, or wait until one of them is available (eg. using `select` from the parent thread or `signal` from the child thread), and possibly kill the other one (using a signal again, or `kill`).

For a very good reference on system programming (multi-processing, threads, communications, concurrency..), see [Unix system programming in Objective Caml](http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/). It has an example (`psearch` [here](http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/threads.html#@default149)) where threads collaborate to find a result, and stop as soon as one of them succeeded.

Comment: Oh yes, this document is originally based on a system programming course given by Xavier, even before Caml Special Light. I would have loved to be there.